# Sequelize nodejs included model attributes name aliasing

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

in my controller i have an included model countries which should return  the raw data as CON.name.CON is the alias name for included model. I want to change the columns name. CON.name to countryName

**Code**

```
let include = [{ 
  model: country , all:true }]

   const Addr = await Address.findAll({
    order: [['isDefaultAddress', 'DESC']],
    where: {
      Id: parseInt(params.req.body.id),
      status: 1,
    },         
    include:include,
    raw:true,
    attributes:{ exclude: [], include:['con.name']}
```

**Response**

```
CON.createdAt: "2020-04-02T12:35:52.205Z"
CON.id: 1
CON.name: "Afghanistan"
CON.updatedAt: "2020-04-02T12:35:52.205Z"
```

**Expected Result**

```
countryCreatedAt: "2020-04-02T12:35:52.205Z"
countryId: 1
countryName: "Afghanistan"
countryUpdatedAt: "2020-04-02T12:35:52.205Z"
```

Answer (score 3):

use **attributes** this way :

```
  attributes: [['con.id','countryId'],
               ['con.name', 'countryName'],
               ['con.createdAt','countryCreatedAt'],
               ['con.updatedAt','countryUpdatedAt']
              ]
```

Comment: @saurabha mistry

Comment: @john , provide column name as it is in database

Answer (score 0):

correct answer that i figured out...

```
 attributes: {exclude: [],
             include: [[Sequelize.col('con.name'), 'countryName'], 
              [Sequelize.col('st.name'), 'stateName']]},
```